# Handling error messages in browser console while using fetch

Tags: javascript, browser, fetch

> Problem:

I am seeing following error in my browser console, I don't want a solution to resolve this error.
I want a solution to remove from the browser console.

```
GET https://logo.clearbit.com/objectivepartners.com net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

[image]

I came to following `solution` which can handle consoling but while using `fetch`
it is not working:

```
console.defaultError = console.error.bind(console);
console.errors = [];
console.error = function(){
    if (!arguments[0].includes("404")) {    
      console.defaultError.apply(console, arguments);
    }
    console.errors.push(Array.from(arguments));
}

fetch("https://logo.clearbit.com/objectivepartners.com").then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                 console.log("okay");              
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error("404"); // WILL NOT SHOW IN BROUSER CONSOLE
            console.error("error"); // WILL SHOW IN BROWSER CONSOLE
        });
```

Here, 
I want if `arguments` include `404` then do not console it in the browser.
But on the fetch request failure, it includes 404 still it consoling, that I do not want to be happening

could it be possible that when `fetch fail` i can disable using in this code (by changing) or any other way?

Comment: Adding a `catch` to `fetch` doesn't fix it, unfortunately. I wouldn't be surprised if it's not possible without a customized browser. Or, for `fetch`, you could bounce the requests off of your *own* server that doesn't give a CORS error, to avoid the warning in the client's console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I didn't find any solution to resolve at the `client-side` or `using javascript`.

But I resolve this by creating an endpoint to API side and giving URL to that API to check that URL is valid or not, based on API response I handled in fetch